# SQL query to return random selection but split evently against a value

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's say i have a table that looks like the below, at the moment I have a simple query that returns a random selection like this

```
Select * from table order by rand() limit 3
```

But what sort of query would I need to ensure that get a selection from each AREA from the table below to avoid the chance of just one area being return

| Name | Area |
| --- | --- |
| A | AreaA |
| B | AreaA |
| C | AreaA |
| D | AreaB |
| E | AreaB |
| F | AreaC |
| G | AreaC |
| H | AreaC |
| I | AreaC |
| J | AreaC |
| K | AreaC |

Comment: Do you have exactly 3 areas in the table? Then union 3 queries.

Comment: No there is actually up to 100 so a union would be massive sadly, but thanks for that idea anyway

Answer (score 0):

Aa a joke (but workable nevertheless):

```sql
WITH 
cte1 AS ( SELECT * 
          FROM table 
          ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 2 ),
cte2 AS ( SELECT * 
          FROM table
          WHERE (    Area NOT IN ( SELECT Area
                              FROM cte1 )
                  OR 2 = ( SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Area)
                           FROM cte1 ) )
            AND Name NOT IN ( SELECT Name 
                              FROM cte1 )
          ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1 )
SELECT * FROM cte1
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM cte2;
```

Answer (score 0):

For MySql 8.0+ you can use `ROW_NUMBER()` window function with `ORDER BY RAND()` in the `OVER` clause and pick the *1st* row of each group:

```
SELECT Name, Area
FROM (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Area ORDER BY RAND()) rn
  FROM tablename
) t
WHERE rn = 1
```

If you have only these 2 columns in the table it is easier with `FIRST_VALUE()` window function:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       FIRST_VALUE(Name) OVER (PARTITION BY Area ORDER BY RAND()) Name,
       Area 
FROM tablename
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9f2593f55fb0e9b4d8307aab661ac51f).